# Disk-space loss after failed download

Tags: hard-drive, downloads, disk, storage

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10 on a Dell Vostro 3500.

I tried to download a 7GB file using Mozilla Firefox... The download failed due to insufficient memory although I checked and was supposed to have 11GB free. That is not my problem...

My problem is that now I have only 2.3GB free.
I already deleted the partially downloaded file.

Can anyone help me recover the lost disk space?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What memory are you using for download ? Do you mean disk-space ?

Comment: In computing memory usually refers to RAM, If you are talking about the long-term storage of your computer you should refer to it a Disk-space. Would you be able to clarify and if possible post the actual error you received?

Comment: yes, I edited the title. Hopefully my question is more understandable now.

Answer (score 1):

***Problem solved***

For some reason I found a copy of the downloaded file in my `~/temp/` folder thus inhibiting me from both downloading the file and taking up much space.